# Could not scrape some image links from a webpage using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script using requests and BeautifulSoup library to parse the links of some images from a [webpage](https://www.ethanallen.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-ethanallen-us-Site/en_US/Product-Variation?pid=emersonQS&dwvar_emersonQS_Fabric=Q1031&dwvar_emersonQS_seatingSize=90sofa&step=2). The image links are visible when you use this selector `[class^='cylindo-viewer-frame'] > img[src*='/frames/']` within the search bar (Ctrl + F) after inspecting element. This how [they](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUFmS.jpg) look like in the dom.

I know I can grab those image links using selenium but I would like to stick with requests module. I've noticed several times that there are always possibilities to grab such dynamic content using requests module. I've tried finding those links within script tag and in dev tools but no luck.

Two of the expected links out of 32 are:

```
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/5/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&feature=FABRIC:Q1031&size=1268
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/7/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&feature=FABRIC:Q1031&size=1268
```

This is how I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.ethanallen.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-ethanallen-us-Site/en_US/Product-Variation?pid=emersonQS&dwvar_emersonQS_Fabric=Q1031&dwvar_emersonQS_seatingSize=90sofa&step=2'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".cylindo-viewer-container li[class^='cylindo-viewer-frame'] > img[src*='/frames/']"):
        print(item.get("src"))
```

> How can I grab those image links using requests?

Comment: You surely can produce the image urls using requests module. All you wanna do is form the full-fledged image urls using `product id`,`frame number` and `fabric`.

Answer (score 0):

### Why you should use selenium?

Website serves content dynamically, what is not to handle with requests, cause the information you try to match is not in the response.

Take a look, it is not that hard ;)

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.ethanallen.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-ethanallen-us-Site/en_US/Product-Variation?pid=emersonQS&dwvar_emersonQS_Fabric=Q1031&dwvar_emersonQS_seatingSize=90sofa&step=2"

driver.get(url)
sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for item in soup.select(".cylindo-viewer-container li[class^='cylindo-viewer-frame'] > img[src*='/frames/']"):
        print(item.get("src"))
    
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/3/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&amp;feature=FABRIC:Q1031&amp;size=1268
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/27/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&amp;feature=FABRIC:Q1031&amp;size=1268
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/29/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&amp;feature=FABRIC:Q1031&amp;size=1268
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/11/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&amp;feature=FABRIC:Q1031&amp;size=1268
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/31/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&amp;feature=FABRIC:Q1031&amp;size=1268
https://content.cylindo.com/api/v2/4616/products/657285/frames/5/657285.JPG?background=FFFFFF&amp;feature=FABRIC:Q1031&amp;size=1268
...
```

Comment: I never mentioned it is hard to use selenium. I use them as a last resort. However, I would like to stick with requests in this very case. Thanks for your solution anyway @HedgeHog.

Comment: Following your question, happy to learn if there is a way to get the goal with requests.